# How to calculate bond angle in protein db file?

Tags: math, bioinformatics

If I have three x,y,z coordinates for protein backbone (N-Ca-C-N-Ca-C....) as such:

```
N -14.152 0.961 4.712
CA -13.296 0.028 3.924
C -11.822 0.338 4.193
N -11.121 -0.642 4.703
CA -9.669 -0.447 4.998
C -8.861 -1.586 4.373
```

how can I calculate the "bond angles" (Ni-Cai-Ci, Cai-Ci-Ni+1, Ci-Ni+1-CAi+1)?

Comment: maybe this belong in the chemistry section?http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If this is a programming question, you probably need to specify the language/library you are using.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361412/finding-the-angle-between-three-points

Comment: zero323: Thanks, I did not see that site on math stack exchange. Lev Levitsky: Thanks, I am using Perl

Comment: Quick search results: [1](http://www.biostars.org/p/17244/), [2](http://search.cpan.org/~rulix/Bio-PDB-Structure-0.02/lib/Bio/PDB/Structure.pm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic vector geometry. The dot-product of two normalized vectors is the cosine of the angle between them.

F'rinstance:

```
N -14.152 0.961 4.712
CA -13.296 0.028 3.924
C -11.822 0.338 4.193
```

(N-Ca) = (-14.152 0.961 4.712) - (-13.296 0.028 3.924) = (-0.856, 0.933, 0.778)
normalized: (-0.576, 0.628, 0.524)

(C-Ca) = (-11.822 0.338 4.193) - (-13.296 0.028 3.924) = ( 1.474, 0.310, 0.269)
normalized: (0.963, 0.203, 0.176)

dot-product: (-0.576, 0.628, 0.524) x (0.963, 0.203, 0.176) = -0.335
angle = acos(-0.335) = 109.57 degrees

Comment: Thanks so much, Beta. I had put the points in PyMol, and indeed 109.5 degrees is correct. I originally had the similar output for the dot product (albeit the negative of what you got: 0.333). This gave me a final degree of 70, which is wrong! What I did differently was the N-Ca calculation; my x, y, z coordinates were negative of yours (0.856, -0.933, -0.778). So I guess the vector subtraction, the order matters, huh? And that still seems strange to me.. But thanks again.