# python code to calculate angle between three point using their 3D coordinates

Tags: python, math, numpy

I have write down a code to calculate angle between three points using their 3D coordinates.

```
import  numpy as np

a = np.array([32.49, -39.96,-3.86])

b = np.array([31.39, -39.28, -4.66])

c = np.array([31.14, -38.09,-4.49])

f = a-b # normalization of vectors
e = b-c # normalization of vectors

angle = dot(f, e) # calculates dot product 
print degrees(cos(angle))  # calculated angle in radians to degree
```

output of the code:

```
degree 33.4118214995
```

but when i used one of the software to calculate the same it gives output bit different 120 degree. please help

reference i have used to write the program:

([How to calculate bond angle in protein db file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945705/how-to-calculate-bond-angle-in-protein-db-file))

Comment: 1.) You need to subtract the same point to get the vectors you are looking for (see answer to your other question). 2.) You have to normalize the vectors (that's something else than subtraction!) 3.) what other software did you use? 4.) There are python scripts avaiable at google where you can compare your solution to.

Comment: 5.) You need to use the inverse of the cosine function (acos or arccos). 6.) You have no idea what your code does, right? :)

Comment: @kazemakase yes you are right before writing the code i just follow  the steps mentioned in the  reference that i have added but now a read a lot and have idea  what is going on. Actually i m not from the mathematics background  :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your original code is pretty close. Adomas.m's answer is not very idiomatic numpy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([32.49, -39.96,-3.86])
b = np.array([31.39, -39.28, -4.66])
c = np.array([31.14, -38.09,-4.49])

ba = a - b
bc = c - b

cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
angle = np.arccos(cosine_angle)

print np.degrees(angle)
```

Comment: thanks Eric for your great help. kindly explain what is going on in line 10 (cosine_angle = -----), and how this code is more idiomatic numpy than  adomas.m. I am very new  in python. thanks

Comment: More idiomatic because of `dot` and array division, and because important everything into the global namespace (`from x import *`) is generally frowned upon. The variables in the other answer are poorly named, Division distributes over dot product, so `dot(ba / q, bc / r) == dot(ba, bc) / (q * r)`, which also has the bonus of being faster

Answer (score 1):

I guess numpy is quite enough:

```
    from numpy import *
    from numpy.linalg import norm
    a = array([32.49, -39.96,-3.86])
    b = array([31.39, -39.28, -4.66])
    c = array([31.14, -38.09,-4.49])
    f = b-a 
    e = b-c 
    abVec = norm(f)
    bcVec = norm(e)
    abNorm = f / abVec;
    bcNorm = e / bcVec;
    res = abNorm[0] * bcNorm[0] + abNorm[1] * bcNorm[1] + abNorm[2] * bcNorm[2];
    angle = arccos(res)*180.0/ pi
    print angle
```

also the res can be calculated with dot:

```
    res = abNorm[0] * bcNorm[0] + abNorm[1] * bcNorm[1] + abNorm[2] * bcNorm[2];
    res = dot(abNorm, bcNorm)
```

Comment: thanks for the correction you have made. Kindly explain the lines from 10-13 if possible it would be great thanks a lot .

Comment: `array([f[0] / abVec, f[1] / abVec, f[2] / abVec])` is better spelt `f / abVec`

Comment: Thanks Eric...adding to answer.

Comment: jax lines 10-13 means that vectors ab and bc are normalized and the distance between those are found which then with the help of arccos translates to angle. Maybe someone has a more detailed and elaborate explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

For 2D, you can use this method using the math library.

```
 import math
 
def getAngle(a, b, c):
    ang = math.degrees(math.atan2(c[1]-b[1], c[0]-b[0]) - math.atan2(a[1]-b[1], a[0]-b[0]))
    return ang + 360 if ang < 0 else ang
 
print(getAngle((5, 0), (0, 0), (0, 5)))
```

Credits: https://manivannan-ai.medium.com/find-the-angle-between-three-points-from-2d-using-python-348c513e2cd

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a big list of (x,y,z) coordinates, this works:

```py
import numpy
def compute_angle_between_3d_points(a,b,c):
    ba = a - b
    bc = c - b

    cosine_numerator = np.sum(ba*bc, axis=1)
    cosine_denominator_1 = np.linalg.norm(ba, axis=1)
    cosine_denominator_2 = np.linalg.norm(bc, axis=1)
    cosine_angle = cosine_numerator / (cosine_denominator_1 * cosine_denominator_2)
    angles = np.arccos(cosine_angle)
    degree_angles = np.rad2deg(angles)

    return degree_angles
```

Above, a,b,c are presumed to be of shape (N_Points, 3).  Something in TensorFlow or Torch would surely be faster, but there you go.